# access DataFrame imported with FileChooser

Tags: methods, rpy2, instances, dataframe, filechooser

I would import a csv file into python with FileChooser. Then when using rpy2, I can perform Statistical analyses with R I know much better compared to Python. Below is a piece of my code:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require("2.0")
import gtk
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import DataFrame
def get_open_filename(self):
        filename = None
        chooser = gtk.FileChooserDialog("Open File...", self.window,
                                        gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN,
                                        (gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL, 
                                         gtk.STOCK_OPEN, gtk.RESPONSE_OK))

        response = chooser.run()
        if response == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
            don = DataFrame.from_csvfile(chooser.get_filename())
            print(don) 
            chooser.destroy()
        return filename
```

When runing the code, `don` is printed. But the question is: in `don`, there are two columns, X and Y I can't access to perform analyses. Thanks for your kind help

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the documentation about [extracting elements](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.3/html/vector.html#extracting-elements) from a `DataFrame` ?

Comment: Yes I have read previoulsy how to get a column of a DataFrame. Sorry, my question was not clear enough. It is more related on how to get the local DataFrame >don> which is defined in <def get_open_filename(self)> under a class. I am very new in Python and this might be answered somewhere but I was unable to find it.

Comment: I am not completely sure of what you have in mind for `get_open_filename()` but I suggest that you take it step by step and start by going through an introduction to Python. It should help clarify things.